# Pushing existing git repository to gitolite

Tags: git-push, gitolite

I've set up gitolite on my Ubuntu server and can add users, create empty repositories, clone the empty repository, add files, commit locally, and `git push origin master` to send it to gitolite.

I can also create a project in XCode4, with its own git repository, and commit changes locally.

Now I want to have another copy in gitolite (possibly so others can use, but also as another copy).  This is where I'm stuck, and I'm a complete newbie to git (only really have used the XCode git functionality).  Can someone direct me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add another remote to your existing repository:

```
git remote add newremote git@gitolite.com:gitolite_repo
```

These values will be changed to suit your needs:

- newremote is the name of the new remote (it's like origin, which you've already been using.)
- git is the username
- gitolite.com is the server
- gitolite_repo is the repo inside gitolite you want to use

When you want to push to origin, you can do that as you always have. When you want to push to the new remote you just do:

```
git push newremote branch
```

Comment: I used the repository name instead of the branch name in the first command

Comment: Before this is possible, the repos must be added to the gitolite admin config and proper access rights given. Maybe it is worthwhile to mention.

Comment: Adding the --all option to the `git push` command might also be helpful in some cases.

Comment: The `git push --all` is mentioned in the old gitolite documentation no [moving repos](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/moverepos.html)

Comment: This seems much easier and cleaner than the in the [official documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin/#appendix-1-bringing-existing-repos-into-gitolite).

Answer (score 3):

Using the information provided by User1578, I was able to add an existing repo to my development server's gitolite repo.

Steps involved:

- Added the repo and pub key (if necessary) to gitolite
- Edited the local .git/config

  - changed the `[remote "origin"]` `url` to my gitolite repo.
- `git push origin master`

Your set up may be different, but I did not need (or want) another branch/remote. The old origin remote was dead anyway, so I did not need to keep it. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create new ("bare" is the default in gitolite) repository (with the same name or with a new name as you wish)
2. Clone the repository that you want to import
3. Open CLI in the cloned repository and change the remote url. e.g:

   git remote set-url origin yourGitoliteUser@your.gitolite.server:YOUR_NEW_REPO
4. Run:

   git push